# Mapping column and table names in EclipseLink

Tags: hibernate, jpa, eclipselink

I used ImprovedNamingStrategy in hibernate, to mapping Java field name to MySQL column name.

ex) birthDate field -> birth_date column, AccountRole class -> account_role table

I'm doing test migrating hibernate code to eclipselink code.

What is the equivalent in EclipseLink to hibernamte's ImprovedNamingStrategy ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is an equivalent.

Where are you using this?  For auto-mapping?  You could use a JPA tool (such as Eclipse Dali) that will generate the JPA orm.xml or annotations from an object model, they may give more control over how the data model is generated.

In general using JPA but not the standard naming default will not be portable.  If you want a mapping to use something different than the default, you should use the @Column annotation or xml.

Comment: Thank you for answer. Currently returned to using Hibernate. I'll try EclipseLink later again.

Answer (score 4):

```
public class MyCustomizer implements SessionCustomizer {

    public void customize(Session session) throws Exception {
        Map<Class, ClassDescriptor> descs = session.getDescriptors();
        Collection<ClassDescriptor> descriptors = descs.values();
        for (ClassDescriptor desc : descriptors) {
            updateMappings(desc);
        }
    }

    private void updateMappings(ClassDescriptor desc) {
        for (DatabaseMapping mapping : desc.getMappings()) {
            if (mapping.isDirectToFieldMapping()) {
                DirectToFieldMapping directMapping = (DirectToFieldMapping) mapping;
                String name = directMapping.getAttributeName();
                String regex = "([a-z])([A-Z]+)";
                String replacement = "$1_$2";
                String newName = name.replaceAll(regex, replacement)
                        .toUpperCase();
                directMapping.getField().resetQualifiedName(newName);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Insert into persistence.xml the property:

```
  <property name="eclipselink.session.customizer" value="com.test.MyCustomizer" />
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears possible through the use of the SessionCustomizer interface:

http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/eclipselink-users/msg00094.html

**EDIT:** unfortunately after spending a bit of time trying to make this work, it does not seem to work, or at least not easily. Note that this link was from 2008.